# Is this.state current when the setState updater is called?

Tags: reactjs

I understand that a fully updated state is passed to setState's callback. I would like to know, though, if this.state is also current at that time. The reason being that I have a method which uses this.state, and I'd like to know if it's safe to call from inside the callback. Example:

```
areWeBigger = () => {
  const { theirSize } = this.props;
  const { ourSize } = this.state;

  return ourSize > theirSize;
};

attemptToEat = () => {
  this.setState(({ ourSize }) => {
    const bigger = this.areWeBigger(); // Is this safe?

    return { ourSize: bigger ? ourSize + 1 : ourSize - 1 }; 
  });
};
```

**EDIT**

I realize now that what I've been calling the "callback" is actually called the "updater". Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Sorry, I just want to be clear. You're talking about this.state also, and not only the state param, correct?

Comment: this.areWeBigger() is before the state change. this.setState(param1, param2), where param1 know only the current state and param2 (the callback) the updated one.

Comment: Your example would be *way more* readable and easier to digest if you didn't use object destructuring syntax to pass argumenrs to the state updater function.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should work. The syntax is also a bit different from what you have used. You are not using the `callback` in the above example,  but rather using the functional convention of `setState` method. Please refer [React JS Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#other-apis-1) for more information about the same. Also, the following snippet might present a better approach towards what you are trying to achieve.

```js
const areWeBigger = () => {
  const { theirSize } = this.props;
  const { ourSize } = this.state;
  return ourSize > theirSize;
};

const attemptToEat = () => {
  this.setState({ ourSize: "whatever value" }, () => {
    const bigger = this.areWeBigger(); // it is okay to use this
    // it doesn't return anything, that is not supported so remove your return statement
    // ideally you can also use componentDidUpdate lifecycle method if you don't want to always trigger a callback, you can refer react docs.
  })
     
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't need setState callback in your case.

From [here](https://itnext.io/react-setstate-usage-and-gotchas-ac10b4e03d60), you can call setState like this:

```
this.setState((prevState, props) => {
  return {counter: prevState.counter + props.step};
})
```

So you can call your areWeBigger function like this:

```
areWeBigger = (ourSize , theirSize ) => {
  return ourSize > theirSize;
};

attemptToEat = () => {
  this.setState(({ ourSize }, {theirSize }) => { //extract ourSize and theiSize from (current)state and props respectively
    const bigger = this.areWeBigger(ourSize, theirSize ); // this is before the state is updated
    return { ourSize: bigger ? ourSize + 1 : ourSize - 1 }; 
  });
};
```

To keep it in your way with direct state access in "areWeBigger":

```
areWeBigger = () => {
  const {ourSize} = this.state;
  const {theirSize} = this.props;
  return ourSize > theirSize;
};

callback = () => {
  // ... here the state is up to date
}

attemptToEat = () => {
  this.setState(({ ourSize }) => { //extract ourSize and theiSize from (current)state and props respectively
    const bigger = this.areWeBigger(); // this is before the state is updated
    return { ourSize: bigger ? ourSize + 1 : ourSize - 1 }; 
  }, callback); // to see the use of callback
};
```

Comment: Sorry, my terminology was off. I actually meant "updater", not "callback". I did realize I can do it as shown in your example, thanks. However, the areWeBigger() method is called in multiple places in my component. It would be cleaner if this.state could simply be accessed inside of it (eliminating the need to pass params for each occurrence). It seems possible (or even likely) that prevState is just there for convenience, since you're always going to access state within the updater. My question, therefore, is whether or not I can do the above without passing the params to areWeBigger().